# UIWebView prevent reload when interfaceorientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have uiwebview and i would like to prevent reload the current url when i change orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa.

Do you have any idea?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    website.delegate = self;
    [self home];
}

- (void)home {
    // Create a URL object
    NSURL *isuURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.com"];
    // URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:isuURL];
    // Load the request in the UIWebView
    [website loadRequest:requestObject];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is help you:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
[super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
{
    [website stopLoading];
} else if ([website isLoading])
{
    [website reload]; // or [website loadRequest:requestObject];
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY This:

```
if(! [myWebView isLoading])
    {
        NSURL *isuURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.com"];
    // URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:isuURL];
    // Load the request in the UIWebView
    [website loadRequest:requestObject];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot guys for your help.

Here is the final solution to my problem

```
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        if ([website isLoading]) {
            [website reload];
        }
        else {
            [website stopLoading];
        }
    }

    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        if ([website isLoading]) {
            [website reload];
        }
        else {
            [website stopLoading];
        }
    }
}
```